# Formatting decimal places with unknown number

Tags: swift, logic

I'm printing out a number whose value I don't know. In most cases the number is whole or has a trailing .5. In some cases the number ends in .25 or .75, and very rarely the number goes to the thousandths place. How do I specifically detect that last case? Right now my code detects a whole number (0 decimal places), exactly .5 (1 decimal), and then reverts to 2 decimal spots in all other scenarios, but I need to go to 3 when it calls for that.

```
class func getFormattedNumber(number: Float) -> NSString {

    var formattedNumber = NSString()

    // Use the absolute value so it works even if number is negative
    if (abs(number % 2) == 0) || (abs(number % 2) == 1) {  // Whole number, even or odd
        formattedNumber = NSString(format: "%.0f", number)
    }

    else if (abs(number % 2) == 0.5) || (abs(number % 2) == 1.5) {
        formattedNumber = NSString(format: "%.1f", number)
    }

    else {
        formattedNumber = NSString(format: "%.2f", number)
    }

    return formattedNumber

}
```

Comment: try this in the last else scope :  formattedNumber = NSString(format: "%.3f", number)

Comment: I want to actually detect whether the number goes to 3 places, I don't want to simply fall back on that.

Comment: Note that neither Float nor Double can represent all decimal fractions exactly. If the user inputs 1.23 it would be stored (roughly) as 1.2300000190734863. How would you display that? – In other words, the "number of decimal places" has no precise meaning for binary floating point values.

Comment: If the number is 6.5 the code properly matches the remainder to exactly .5. Wouldn't it not much if there were trailing 0's tacked on by the system?

Comment: 6.5 *can* be represented exactly as a Float. Most decimal fractions *can't*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `Float` uses a binary (IEEE 754) representation and cannot represent
all decimal fractions precisely. For example,

```
let x : Float = 123.456
```

stores in `x` the bytes `42f6e979`, which is approximately 
`123.45600128173828`. So does `x` have 3 or 14 fractional digits?

You can use `NSNumberFormatter` if you specify a *maximum number*
of decimal digits that should be presented:

```
let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 3
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0

println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123)!)      // 123
println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123.4)!)    // 123.4
println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123.45)!)   // 123.45
println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123.456)!)  // 123.456
println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123.4567)!) // 123.457
```

---

**Swift 3/4 update:**

```
let fmt = NumberFormatter()
fmt.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 3
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0

print(fmt.string(for: 123.456)!) // 123.456
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Comment: Awesome, setting locale was missing in all answers I came across, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%g` to suppress trailing zeros. Then I think you do not need to go through the business of determining the number of places. Eg -

```
var num1:Double = 5.5
var x = String(format: "%g", num1) // "5.5"

var num2:Double = 5.75
var x = String(format: "%g", num2) // "5.75"
```

Or this variation where the number of places is specified. Eg -

```
var num3:Double = 5.123456789
var x = String(format: "%.5g", num3) // "5.1235"
```

Comment: But note that the number 5 is the *total* number of digits, so `String(format: "%.5g", 51245.789)` gives 51246 without any fractional digits, and %g can switch to exponential representation, e.g. `String(format: "%.5g", 512457.89)` gives 5.1246e+05.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents ;) Swift 3 ready

Rounds the floating number and strips the trailing zeros to the required minimum/maximum fraction digits.

```
extension Double {
    func toString(minimumFractionDigits: Int = 0, maximumFractionDigits: Int = 2) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = minimumFractionDigits
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = maximumFractionDigits

        return formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Double(394.239).toString() // Output: 394.24
Double(394.239).toString(maximumFractionDigits: 1) // Output: 394.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a floating point number to 3 decimal places, you can use `String(format: "%.3f")`.  This will round, so `0.10000001` becomes `0.100`, `0.1009` becomes `0.101` etc.

But it sounds like you don’t want the trailing zeros, so you might want to trim them off.  (is there a way to do this with `format`? edit: yes, `g` as @simons points out)

Finally, this really shouldn’t be a class function since it’s operating on primitive types.  Better to either make it a free function, or perhaps extend `Double`/`Float`:

```
extension Double {
    func toString(#decimalPlaces: Int)->String {
        return String(format: "%.\(decimalPlaces)g", self)
    }
}

let number = -0.3009
number.toString(decimalPlaces: 3)  // -0.301
```