# Double format with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, double, number-formatting

I need to display double numbers in a `UILabel` but I have a rule if the number will double without having fractional value then it can be display in Integer format i.e. 4.0 just display 4 but if the number is 4.879770 just display two decimals round up.

I made the first part works with:

```
let number = 4.99

if number - Double(Int(number)) == 0 {
   print(Int(number))
} else {
   print(String(format: "%.2f", number))
}
```

But I hope that there is a better way

Comment: Use a number formatter, examples  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621338/formatting-decimal-places-with-unknown-number

Answer (score 1):

This is more flexible algorithm of rounding to N significant digits

Swift 3 solutions

```
extension Double {
// Rounds the double to 'places' significant digits
  func roundTo(places:Int) -> Double {
    guard self != 0.0 else {
        return 0
    }
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places) - ceil(log10(fabs(self))))
    return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
  }
}


// Double(0.123456789).roundTo(places: 2) = 0.12
// Double(1.23456789).roundTo(places: 2) = 1.2
// Double(1234.56789).roundTo(places: 2) = 1200
```

Or you can use NSNumberFormatter if you specify a maximum number of decimal digits that should be presented as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30622335/1556386) by martin:

```
let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 3
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0

println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123)!)      // 123
println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123.4)!)    // 123.4
println(fmt.stringFromNumber(123.45)!)   // 123.45
```