# NSNumberFormatter check specific decimals

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting, formatter, nsnumberformatter

I would like to be able to check some prices' decimals and display them only of they are different from 0.

Ex:

[image]

It would be great to print `122,14` for `Litecoin` here.

Here is my `NumberFormatter` code so far:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 4
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "\(SettingsViewController.currencyCode)")
    value.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))
```

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621338/formatting-decimal-places-with-unknown-number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `minimumFractionDigits = 4`, set `maximumFractionDigits = 4`, or set both:

```
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
```